# Which are integral domain

Tags: ring-theory

[image]

I know that $\mathbb Z[i]/n\mathbb Z[i]$ is an integral domain $\iff \langle n\rangle =n\mathbb Z[i]$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb Z[i]\iff n$ is an prime element of $\mathbb Z[i].$

- $2=(1+i)(1-i)$ where none of $1+i,1-i$ are units of $\mathbb Z[i].$ So $2$ is not irreducible and hence not prime.
- $13=(3+2i)(3-2i)$ where none of $3+2i,3-2i$ are units of $\mathbb Z[i].$ So $13$ is not irreducible and hence not prime.

What about the rest. I can't find out. Please help.

Comment: What do the same arguments tell you about those_

Comment: For $7,19$ I couldn't find out such combinations

Comment: Ok, so since such combinations do not exist (it is after all a finite problem to check for them, so if we cannot find them, we know they do not exist), what does that tell you?

Comment: I can't get why this is a finite problem of checking?

Comment: Ohh, I assumed you were using the norm for this. Are you familiar with the norm on the Gaussian integers?

Comment: $N(x+iy)=|x^2+y^2|?$

Comment: Yes, precisely. So if you can factor an element, that means you can factor the norm, which means...?

Comment: $7=xy\implies N(7)=49=N(xy)=N(x)N(y).$ So unless $x,y$ are units $7=N(x)??????$

Comment: Ohh so $a^2+b^2=7\implies$ we are to search for $a,b$ from $1~to~7$

Comment: but no such $a,b$ exists so $7$ is irreducible and since $\mathbb  Z[i]$ is ED and hence a PID so it is prime. Is it okay?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely the sort of argument to use here, and you can do the same for $19$.

Comment: Thanks so much. I appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

*Based on the comments above I'm providing the proof:*

Since $\mathbb Z[i]$ is an ED and hence a PID we should check whether $7,19$ are irreducible.

- $7 $: If $7$ is not irreducible then let $7=xy$ where $x,y$ are nonunits and so $N(7)=N(x)N(y)\implies49=N(x)N(y).$ Since $x,y$ are nonunits $N(x),N(y)\ne 1$ so $N(x)=7.$ Let $x=a+ib.$ There's no $a,b$ in $\{0,1,2,...,7\}$ such that $a^2+b^2=7!$ So $7$ is irreducible.
- $19$: Similar

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft :P

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to think about the problem:

> **Theorem**: Let $p$ be a rational prime (that is prime in $\Bbb Z$). Then $p$ is a prime in Gaussian Integers $\Bbb Z[i]$ iff $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

Since $\Bbb Z \backslash n \Bbb Z$ is an Integral Domain iff  $n$ is prime in $\Bbb Z[i]$, it follows that only options 3,4 will hold.