# Find out $n$ for which following is an integral domain?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $\mathbb Z[\iota]$ denote the ring of Gaussian integers. For which of the following $n$ is the quotient ring $\frac{\mathbb Z[\iota]}{n\mathbb Z[\iota]}$ is an Integral Domain?

1) $2$

2) $13$

3) $19$

4) $7$

I know that $\frac{\mathbb Z[\iota]}{n\mathbb Z[\iota]}$ $\simeq$ $\mathbb Z_n[\iota]$.But i donot know when $\mathbb Z_n[\iota]$ is integral domain?

Comment: The critical point of an integral domain is not having zero divisors, right?

Comment: @ abiessu yes ..

Comment: So are there any of the $n$ in the options which make a ring with no zero divisors?

Comment: for any given $n$ in options $\mathbb Z_n$ is field.

Comment: The ring $\;\Bbb Z[i]/n\Bbb Z[i]\;$ is an integral domain iff $\;n\Bbb Z[i]\;$ is a prime integral iff (this ring is Euclidean) $\;n\;$ is a prime element. Do you know what integer primes remain prime in the gaussian integers?

Comment: @user290972 I don't think so. For example, observe that $\;13=(2+3i)(2-3i)\;$

Comment: @ Joanpemo I talk about $\mathbb Z_n$

Comment: @user290972 Oh, I see. Sorry. Then yes, you are right in that.

Comment: @Joanpemo. No i don't know about that

Comment: @user290972 I think you shall need that: only primes whose norm equal a prime $=3\pmod4\;$ are gaussina primes. This is why $\;13\;$ is not.

Comment: i got answer, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608883/which-are-integral-domain?rq=1